# garage door remote doesn't work at night

Tags: garage-door-opener

We can't close or open the garage door remotely at night for many months.  It works in the daytime but not at night. Weird.  I can't find any answers.  Batteries are good (we use two separate remotes. One came with the opener, and the other is programmed into the buttons in the car.  Yet, neither work at night (or when it is dark). But why?

Comment: Make/model of garage door opener?

Comment: did you try without any lights on

Comment: If the remotes don't work, how do you open the door?  Is the garage door opener outlet on a timer?

Comment: Is the opener getting power all night, or might the circuit be on a timer -- or on a switch that isn't usually turned on after hours? Only other thought I've got is that there might be some kind of radio interference.

Comment: Maybe the power connection is miswired somehow, so that when the garage lights are on, the opener gets no power.

Comment: Is this a long standing problem or did it just start happening.  If it just started happening, what work was done around the garage or house could conceivably have caused this?

Comment: I’ve tried with garage light off and garage light on no difference the remote does work at night once  I’m parked inside the garage. Long standing problem we had the windows replaced recently? But that’s it as far as construction. One window in garage. It is a detached garage so when I come home at night I stop the car in the driveway then I walk around to the door to the garage and open the garage door using the button on the wall.

Comment: is there an optical sensor on the door?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're not using LED bulbs in the openers. I had this same issue and that was the culprit for me. Swapping the bulbs out for LEDs designed specifically for garage door openers, or using CFL/Incandescents, solved the problem for me.

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Answer (score 1):

Did this change in behavior happen to correspond with changing light bulbs in the opener or anywhere garage area (such as accent lights, etc.)?  Many LED light bulbs (especially inexpensive ones) cause radio frequency signal interference with the remote opener signal.  To test, make sure there are no LED bulbs turned on anywhere near your opener and try it then.  You can either get bulbs specially made to co-exist with garage door openers, or replace with CFL or the older incandescent bulbs.

Comment: sadly, most newer LEDs don't use SMPSs and thus won't cause interference (such bulbs tend to dim better and last longer) . my point is to just try the newest and cheapest bulbs you can get (think dollar tree) instead of more expensive garage-targeted bulbs.

Comment: The light  in the opener itself hasn’t worked for a while now but we do have fluorescent lighting inside the garage but it’s rarely on.